# Reference to non-static Member Function

Tags: c++, sorting, maps, comparator, non-static

https://leetcode.com/problems/sort-array-by-increasing-frequency/

In this leetcode question, I wrote the following code:

```c++
class Solution {
public:
    bool compare(pair<int,int>p1,pair<int,int>p2)
    {
        if(p1.second<p2.second)
            return true;
        else if(p1.second==p2.second)
        {
            if(p1.first>p2.first)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
    vector<int> frequencySort(vector<int>& nums) {
        vector<int>final(nums.size());int k=0;map<int,int>mpp;
        for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
        {
            mpp[nums[i]]++;
        }
        sort(mpp.begin(),mpp.end(),compare);
        for(auto it:mpp)
        {
            while(it.second)
            {
                final[k++]=it.first;
                it.second--;
            }
        }
        return final;
    }
};
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Line 23: Char 36: error: reference to non-static member function must be called
        sort(mpp.begin(),mpp.end(),compare);
                                   ^~~~~~~
```

Can someone please point out the mistake? (PS: I am new to Object Oriented Programming)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [std::sort function with custom compare function results error: reference to non-static member function must be called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767847/stdsort-function-with-custom-compare-function-results-error-reference-to-non)

Comment: I found an exact duplicate of your question in ten seconds. Please search SO before asking a question.

Comment: @Botje ,I had tried that but the issue persists.

Comment: Please show us the different error you get when add the `static` keyword to `compare`, because it works for me.

Comment: @Botje,In file included from prog_joined.cpp:1:
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int>>' and 'std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int>>')
                   
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_algo.h:4899:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization

Comment: You cannot sort an `std::map`. You need to rethink that part.

Comment: Thats why I had asked the qsn,despite a similar one being in SO.Thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can dump the `map`'s pairs into a `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` first:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> intermediate(mpp.begin(), mpp.end());
std::sort(begin(intermediate), end(intermediate), compare);
```

and then walk `intermediate` instead.

Comment: Ya definitely..

Answer (score -1):

In C++ Maps cannot be sorted even if you use a Custom Comparator.